# Designing sane messaging paradigm for concurrent updates

Tags: design, messaging, apache-kafka, queue, asynchronous

We have a weird use-case that I need to support in my application and needed some opinions on how to design it.

At a basic level the application allows users to work on a "list" of "tweets" she cares about

- To work on any list the user "locks" the list and then can do actions like reordering the tweets, add some small comments etc and then "save" (*save sends a message over kafka for the updated list*)
- While the list is "locked" no other user can work on the same list
- 2 different lists can have tweets in common.

Now the weird case we need to support is an operation we are calling "**torpedo**":

- "Torpedo" will allow any user who has locked a list, to make certain updates to a tweet in that list which it can "torpedo" to every list that contains that tweet (even if they are locked by another user, and the other user can continue working).
- That tweet gets updated across the board

Though the user-interface is a challenge, my question is more about the messaging of these updates:

- For a single list update a message (containing all the tweets in that list) is sent over kafka with the key being the list-id.
- The messages for a same list always go to the same partition and are hence processed in-order

**Now for a torpedo we have to send a message containing ALL the lists that were updated.**

The problems I have:

1. I cannot choose a single list-id as key which means that torpedo
   message containing an update for list-id-1 could go in a different
   partition than another regular update to list-id-1 and lead to out-of-order processing of list-id-1 updates
2. The consumer needs to know ALL the lists that were updated as
   part of the torpedo

The only option I could think is to split the torpedo message per list, that will solve (1) above but will make it harder to do (2) but if don't split I can solve (2) but not (1).

Please share any opinions on above and any suggestions on how I can make this a design I can still reason about in future.

Comment: From your feature description, it sounds to me that a torpedo operation changes a tweet and not a list, thus it should be keyed to the tweet. Do you already have operations that make changes to tweets that become visible in all lists containing that tweet (possibly after those lists have been unlocked)?

Comment: The torpedo can change both the tweet and the list. For e.g. User can decide to replace a tweet with another tweet in EVERY list as a torpedo action.  The only operation where changes are applied to different lists at the same time is torpedo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Design solution for updating different lists with common items](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/411077/design-solution-for-updating-different-lists-with-common-items)

Comment: Not exactly but I have got enough to think about this entire workflow and simplify it